# Why is my hovertool, from bokeh showing incorrect results?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, hover, bokeh

My hover tool in bokeh is showing incorrect result when hovering over graph. Here is a part of my code which includes where I define hover tool:

```
headers = ['ticker', 'size', 'price', 'unix','bid','date']
dtypes = {'ticker': 'str', 'size': 'float', 'price': 'float', 'unix': 'float','ask': 'str','date': 'str'}
parse_dates = ['date']
btcnow = pd.read_csv('new 1031-113.csv', header=None, names=headers, dtype=dtypes, parse_dates=parse_dates)
#btc105=pd.read_excel('11-3-11-5 data.xlsx',sheet_name="Sheet1",header=None)
#btc103=btc103.append(btc105,ignore_index = True)
now3 = pd.DataFrame(btcnow, columns=['size','date'])
now4 = pd.DataFrame(btcnow, columns=['date','price','size'])
x1 = now3.loc[now3["size"] == 31, "date"]
y1 = now3.loc[now3["size"] == 31, "size"]
z1= now4.loc[now4["size"] == 31, "date"]
w1=now4.loc[now4["size"] == 31, "price"]
hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[('index', "$index"),
    ("Date", "@date_time{%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f}"),
   ("(x1,y1)", "(@x1, @y1)"),
("(z1,w1)", "(@z1, @w1)"),
])
```

I want to be able to hover over the data and see the date and time, but its showing me the unix time instead, how do I fix that? 
Here is a snippet of my data: [data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKAUR.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not showing you the incorrect result, it's showing you the correct result, formatted in a way that is different than what you want. Formatting hover tooltips is [covered in the documentation](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#formatting-tooltip-fields). You need to tell Bokeh you want a datetime formatter for any field you want a datetime formatter used, by configuring the `formatters` property of the hover tool:

```
formatters={
    '@date_time' : 'datetime', # use 'datetime' formatter for 'date_time' field
}
```

Comment: It is still not working.. is my hovertool , tool tips correct? Also this is the code for figure :
fig1 = figure(plot_height=700, plot_width=1100,tools=tools1,x_axis_type='datetime',
             title='BTC Oct 31- Nov 5')

Comment: There's not enough in your post to speculate further. SO always suggests providing a *complete minimal reproducer* (i.e. code that can be taken and *actually run*) and I am happy to try to debug more if one can be provided. Otherwise all I can suggest is starting from one of the many examples in the docs that might be vaguely similar to your case and gently nudging it towards exactly what you need, in small incremental steps, so you can identify any problem steps exactly.